# How to download a file with app made in Intel XDK?

Tags: javascript, android, html, intel-xdk

So, I found out that the API of Intel XDK doesn't allow to download a file per se, it requires to add a plugin named "InAppBrowser" but I tried to add the plugin and call it with window.open and it doesnt work

`var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');`

Here is the [Plugin's](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser)

Can someone know how to make this work or at least knows how to add a button that allows me to download a file with my app made in Intel XDK?

Comment: You don't need the InAppBrowser, you need this plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer

Answer (score 0):

The APIs you're trying to use **will not work** if you are not running a compiled version of your application. Also, the only way to include a plugin is through the *build settings*, which can be reached by clicking the "PROJECTS" text in the top left-hand corner of the Intel XDK screen.

A few example projects can be found when you create a new project. You can access them by:

- Expanding samples and demos
- Selecting a project
- Clicking "Continue" and then "Create"

Again, **none of the APIs features will work** *until* you go to the build tab, build for your operating system, and then download and install the app. However, you still need to make sure you have all of the appropriate plugins and permissions set in the *build settings*

Side Note:

It may now be possible to test *some* of the API features without building your application. To guarantee that all will work (if configured correctly), it is still recommended to build your app.